# Can't mount another linux server NAS NFS share

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, network-attached-storage

I have a NAS server which is already successfully mounted on one of my servers for backups, but when I tried to do it on another server I get "mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting"

All the guides show me to check the /etc/exports file on the destination server but that file is blank!

How then is the current server backing up every day to this and why is the new one not mounting?

Thanks

Comment: Well, all those guides are right. If the `/etc/exports` is empty, that server will not provide any NFS share that can be mounted by other servers. It might be that this file had an entry, then was mounted on your backup server and the entries in `/etc/exports` were removed. In any case, I would double-check if your backup server actually has mounted the share. Then follow the guides...

Comment: I'm not clear which machine you're referring to as the "destination server". If it's the machine that you're running the mount command on then `/etc/exports` there is irrelevant. It's the copy of `/etc/exports` on the NFS server which matters. Perhaps you could clarify the question with example server names.

Comment: Running `showmount -e theserver` on the machine where you have the NFS volume already mounted is likely to give useful information (replacing `theserver` with the name or IP address of the NFS server).

Comment: The server I want backed up is called LMP2 & the destination/NFS server is called NAS2. I did showmount -e NAS2 and it was blank, even though another server called 'outsource' is successfully mounted to that and backs up every day

Comment: I must add the 'outsource' server was added quite a while ago